# How to maintain fixed size of C variable types over different machines?

Tags: c++, c

I've all this kind of functions.

```
ssize_t fuc1(int var1, void *buf, size_t count);
int func2(char *charPtr, int mode, int dev);
short func3( long var2);
```

problem is that data types in C has different sizes when compiled on different machines(64bit & 32bit). This is true for even void*.  For some reasons. I need to ensure that these sizes all are same on every machine(64bit & 32bit). So, how should I modify these ?

Comment: It might help if you explained why you need the sizes of these parameters to be the same across platforms.

Comment: @John: there's a moderate chance that the data files are going to be written on one machine and read on the other, and as yet, the chips are all Intel and hence little-endian, but SPARC and PPC and big-endianness has not crossed the synapses.

Comment: @Jonathan:  It's possible that he runs these things through some sort of endifier and deendifier program (to coin a couple of words, badly).  Of course, there's no reason whatsoever to worry about `void *` cross-platform representation.

Answer (score 13):

Use C99, `<stdint.h>`, and `int32_t` etc types. [More details on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#Exact-width_integer_types_.28optional.29).

There's no way to do this for pointer types, because they are, by definition, platform-specific. There is no valid use case in which you could possibly need them to be consistent, because they are not serializable. If you use a pointer variable to store pointer *and* other data (e.g. depending on some flag), use a union of some exact integral type with a pointer type. Alternatively, use C99 `uintptr_t`, and cast to pointer when you need to treat it as such.

Answer (score 2):

The old fashioned method to solve your dilemma is to use macros to define a generic type and have these macros defined based on the target platform:

**datatypes.h**

```
#ifndef DATATYPES_H
#define DATATYPES_H

#ifdef PLATFORM_32_BIT
typedef UINT32 unsigned int; // unsigned 32-bit integer
typedef UINT16 unsigned short;
typedef UINT08 unsigned char;
#else
// Assume 64 bit platform
typedef UINT32 unsigned short;
#endif

#endif // DATATYPES_H
```

When you absolutely need a 32-bit unsigned variable, you will use the `UINT32` type.  The platform definition can be passed to the compiler on the command line.

Since I have not worked on a 64-bit platform, you will have to research the bit sizes of the POD types.

Comment: This used to be a good solution. But once the <stdint.h> header was standardardized, the best practice was to use <stdint.h> if available, and if your compiler doesn't yet support it, at least define your own typedefs that are compatible with the names used in <stdint.h>. That way porting to a system that supports <stdint.h> in the future will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not within C++03 or C89. C99 has the `<stdint.h>` header you can use, which defines types like `uint32_t`, etc, but you're outta luck for C++.

If you need it to work in C++03 you need to use something like [Boost::Integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/integer/doc/html/index.html) EDIT or have an implementation of TR1 available.

Comment: C++ TR1 includes `<stdint.h>` updated to the same level as C99 one.

Answer (score 0):

The [POSH library](http://hookatooka.com/poshlib/) (Portable Open Source Harness) may be of help to you. This is created by Brian Hook, author of [Write Portable Code](http://www.hookatooka.com/wpc/).