# Why is the size of fundamental types implementation dependent?

Tags: c++, types, sizeof

I tried to look for a similar question, but didn't find it. Please, point me to it if I missed it.

I know that the size of certain types is only guaranteed to be in certain ranges and to satisfy certain ordering. For instance, the size of a `long` is guaranteed to be no shorter than that of a `int`, but it may be the same. The only exception I found is that a `char` is always of size 1.

My question is: why is this choice left to the implementation? Why isn't this fixed by the standard? Wouldn't it make things easier for the user/programmer if he/she knew for sure that, for instance, using a `long` instead of an `int` would allow his/her code to work with larger numbers *everywhere* (and not just on his machine)? Sure, you can always check the size of a variable at configure time, but still, wouldn't life be easier if the size was guaranteed exactly, without slacks? Why isn't it so? What's the rationale behind this choice?

Comment: Because for some implementations it might have been more convenient to use larger-sized types. There are fixed-size types in C++ if you need that.

Comment: To have a fixed size with, you can use : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Rational was to use `int` as default with better performance than an imposed size.

Comment: If fixed limits were imposed on integer types, code it wouldn't be able to run directly on hardware that cannot natively support those types. You can read about many of the rationales for C here : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

Comment: [“C variable type sizes are machine dependent.” Is it really true?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2533319/995714)

Comment: if you want fixed size, use `int32_t`, `uint64_t`...

Comment: Thanks to whoever edited the question adding the link. That's what I was looking for. And yes, I was aware of `intXXX_t` types, I was just wondering the reason for not enforcing a specific universal default size. That's all.